# How to limit SPSS output decimals?

Tags: spss

I'm quite new to SPSS. Have searched for how to limit the decimals in any output table, but haven't found any valid methods, and the one's I've tried haven't worked out.

My output tables all look like this

[image]

How do I limit the output to say two decimals? The current settings prevent me from exporting directly to word through copy-paste as the exported columns become extremely wide, which is a great future in SPSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a statistic comes from a specific single variable, the number of decimals shown by default is based on the variable format and the type of statistic.  You can reduce the number of decimals for a variable in the Data Editor Variable View or the FORMATS command.

When a statistic has a more complicated source, such as a significance level, the precision is determined by type.  You can always double click the output table and change the displayed decimals or format in the pivot table Editor.